# Centering contents in a Bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a Bootstrap navbar that contains icons on the right and left  with a centered title.  I'm not able to get the text to center properly.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
        <a href="#" id="navMenu" class="navbar-brand"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>

      <!--  Center the contents of this element in the navbar -->
      <div class="navbar-header nav-element-center">
        <span class="h4 ">Centered Title</span>
      </div>


      <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
        <a href="#" id="navMenu" class="navbar-brand pull-right"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

test example: https://jsfiddle.net/goyosoyo/aw0219a4/

Note: I've given the divs a colorized border so that I could see what was happening.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
        <a href="#" id="navMenu" class="navbar-brand"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
        <a href="#" id="navMenu" class="navbar-brand pull-right"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
      <!--  Center the contents of this element in the navbar -->
      <div class="nav-element-center">
        <span class="h4 ">Centered Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-element-center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 14px;
}
```

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aw0219a4/9/)

Comment: Thanks so much. So the div tag simply needed to be moved out from between the two div tags with the right and left pull classes?  Can you explain why this works?

Comment: Exactly, and I removed `navbar-header` class which has `float: left` by default.